# Fluid design issue

Tags: css, responsive-design

Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/fFSZN/2/

You see how part of the `img` gets out of the `div` because of the border. The current width of the `div` (300px) is just set for the example, for real it would be 100% (so I can't hardcode values). My question is how to fit the image and its border into the `div` with CSS only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `box-sizing: border-box` to make this work. Also, note how I set the image to max out at 100% of the containing element's width, while putting the height on auto to maintain proper aspect ratio.

http://jsfiddle.net/fFSZN/6/

More info on border-box from Paul Irish: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/

Comment: I added in the moz vendor prefix. What version of IE are you using? It's a pretty well-supported feature except for IE6/7.

Comment: @j08691 I use Chrome, IE, and Firefox all newest versions and they work fine.  Those old edge cases almost need to not be supported to encourage updating.

Comment: +1 for `box-sizing`, I love learning these little used css attributes :)

Comment: @defaultNINJA - Until he added the vendor prefix it didn't work for me in Firefox. Does now. Still doesn't work in IE8 for me however.

Comment: It might have to do with the page's doctype. If you open up the dev panel in IE8, does it say it's in IE8 standards mode?

Comment: @defaultNINJA "supporting older browsers only encourages users to continue using their old browser" is a myth.  Windows XP is the 2nd most popular OS and cannot upgrade beyond IE8.  Phones cannot be reasonably expected to have the latest browsers (my Android cannot be upgraded beyond version 2.3).

Comment: @cimmanon Most phone's will be viewing a different webpage built for mobile devices anyway.  Also most phones receive automatic updates that are pushed out to users, not all, but most.  Also those XP machine will die eventually, or Microsoft will get tired of dragging along legacy code and kick it to the curb if they haven't already.  Agile development is becoming more popular and encourages more smaller updates to keep up with current tech which adds to this.

Answer (score 1):

First, for it to be a fluid image, give it `max-width: 100%`.

Then, instead of a 5px border on the image, give the containing div 5px padding and a black background.

```
div {
    width:300px;
    border:1px solid red;
    padding:5px;
    background: #000;
}
img {
    max-width:100%;
    display:block;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fFSZN/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the black border around the image. The border on the left side added extra space so it went out of the div's boundaries.

`img { width:100%; display:block; }`

Here's the updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fFSZN/4/